# Why are leader skips seemingly ignored in \vsplit?

Tags: split, glue, leaders

I've gotten an expected result with a `\vplit` on a box with leaders.  The leaders have a fixed amount of glue, plus stretch and shrink.  The fixed amount seems to be ignored in the size calculation, or else TeX is shrinking to get more in the split box than it needs to.  Consider:

```
\setbox1=\vbox{
 \vbox to 50pt{}
 \nobreak
 \leaders \hbox{} \vskip25pt plus 100pt minus 25pt
 \allowbreak
 \nointerlineskip
 \vbox to 50pt{}
 \nobreak
 \leaders \hbox{} \vskip25pt plus 100pt minus 25pt
 \allowbreak
 \nointerlineskip
 \vbox to 50pt{}
 \nobreak
 \leaders \hbox{} \vskip25pt plus 100pt minus 25pt
 \allowbreak}
```

Then:

```
\setbox3=\vsplit1 to 150pt

\showbox3
> \box3=
\vbox(150.0+0.0)x0.0, glue set - 1.0
.\vbox(50.0+0.0)x0.0
.\penalty 10000
.\leaders 25.0 plus 100.0 minus 25.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.\penalty 0
.\vbox(50.0+0.0)x0.0
.\penalty 10000
.\leaders 25.0 plus 100.0 minus 25.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.\penalty 0
.\vbox(50.0+0.0)x0.0
.\penalty 10000
.\leaders 25.0 plus 100.0 minus 25.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.\penalty 0
```

As you can see, TeX puts all three of the inner boxes in `\box3`, although their natural height, including the leaders is 225pt.  There's plenty of stretch to include just two of the inner boxes and get a box whose height is 150pt.  So my question is:  why isn't TeX respecting the `\leader`'s fixed amount of glue in the above example?

(I'm not aware of a `\tracingsplits`, analogous to `\tracingpages`, which shows the calculation.)

Answer (score 2):

TeX doesn't use the stretch because there is enough *shrink* to fit all three boxes, leaving nothing in the original box.

Note that there is an implicit `\penalty -10000` at the end of the vertical material from the box being split [TeXbook page 124].

Comment: The leaders have 25pt of "fixed" glue.  That is ignored.  Just two of the inner boxes plus the fixed glue should allow a split to 150pt.A split is definitely occurring, because you can try

Comment: ... `vsplit to 100pt` and get just the two inner boxes.  TeX is choosing to shrink the glue entirely when it doesn't need to.  Are you saying the implicit `\penalty -10000` at the end is producing such a desirable break point that inner boxes are pushed together?

Comment: No, the fixed glue is not ignored, the glue is shrunk. Yes, I am saying the \penalty -10000 is more desirable than anything else.